# Will a user's channel ID on Youtube v3 API ever change?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am getting a user's upload feed using Youtube v3 API. However this happens in 2 steps. I am firstly getting the Channel ID for the user and then another call to get each item.

```
Get user's Channel ID - https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={{user}}&key={{API key}}
```

```
Get each item in feed using Channel ID - https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId={{User Channel ID}}&key={{API Key}}
```

So once I have got the user's channel ID, is it safe to skip the first step from now on and simply get the feed? Whats the chance that the user channel ID might change?

Comment: better chance of google changing their API before that ! ^

Answer (score 1):

ID must be unique identifier. So changing ID means User channel is recreated. Similar to database ID

Comment: Thanks. What about other ID's such as the uploads channel ID?

Comment: @Fred Same for all ID's. Even outside youtube. SO question ID, facebook page ID and so on. Just keep in mind that entry with that ID can be deleted.